# Filtering values of index page on values defined in drop down box.rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie with rails and I am trying to fliter my index page on values selected by drop down box on index page 
For Eg .In my index page I am having a drop down box showing employee names if user selects a value from drop down list the values of index page should filter with that employee name.
Note- Te Employee name is a cross reference field

**My Controller Look like**

```
def index

  @complaints = Complaint.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @complaints }
  end
end
```

**My Index View Looks like**

```
<%= select("employee", "employee_id", Employee.all.collect {|p| [ p.fullname, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to answer with whatever I can understand from your question and 
I am asssuming u dont want filtering through an ajax call and your complaint table consists of a column named employee_id.

In your index_view add

```
<%= form_tag 'controllers_index_path' , :method => "get", :id=> 'filter_employees_form' do %>
<p>
  <%= select_tag 'employee_id', options_for_select(Employee.all.collect {|p| [p.fullname, p.id ] }, :selected => params[:employee_id]), :prompt => 'Select', :id => 'filter_employees' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Add the following code in the javascript file or add it at the end of your index page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#filter_employees').change(function(){
    $('#filter_employees_form').submit();
  })
})
```

In controller.rb

```
def index

  @complaints = Complaint.get_complaints(params).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @complaints }
  end
end
```

In complaint.rb(model)

```
def self.get_complaints(params)
  conditions = ['']
  conditions = ['complaints.employee_id = ?', params[:employee_id]] if params[:employee_id]
  self.where(conditions)
end
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.